# JTextPane Syntax-Highlighting

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, syntaxhighlighter

I'm currently working on a really simple IDE meant for C programming in Java. And by simple I mean it has minor code-guessing (Similar to Eclipse), some minor auto-completion (Once again, think Eclipse), and some syntax highlighting. I have just about everything figured out and roughed-out (i.e. working, but not pretty or efficient), except I'm having some trouble with proper Syntax highlighting.

What I mean by that is; in my code JFrame, I put in a JTextPane so I could use different fonts, bold, un-bold, italicize, and add different text colors with relative ease. I have a key-listener hooked up to this JTextPane, and on each space-bar press, it grabs what you just wrote, runs it through an "if" statement-tree to see if the word you wrote is a keyword. If you did, it attempts to highlight (or not) what you just wrote. However, there are some cases where I need it to change color before I hit a space-bar (such as a comment, or a #define statement). No problem, right? Just add another "if" statement to detect if that key has been pressed, and if it has, change the font color. Well, that's what I attempted to do, however it isn't working. It is really messing with my mind seeing as I use the EXACT same code to change colors that I do with the space-bar press (which works just dandy).

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense, I'll be happy to explain a bit more if it's required. I also removed as much un-necessary code as possible, to try to shorten it down.

Thank you very much for your time!

~Cent

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class Main implements Runnable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
private static final String NAME = "";
private JFrame frame;
private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
private int keysPressed = -1; /* Keys pressed */
private ArrayList<Integer> keyCode = new ArrayList<Integer>(); /* List of our keyCodes */

public void run()
{
    frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    textPane.setEditable(true);
    textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
                @Override 
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
                {
                     int previousPos; /* Previous position of the caret */
                     int length; /* Length of our grabbed string */

                     int currentPos; /* Current position of the caret */

                     String text; /* The entire text of the JTextPane */
                     String subText; /* Our sub-string-text we're using */
                     String subTextP; /* Our sub-string-text plus one character*/

                     boolean first = true; /* Be default, it's the first letter */

                     StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument(); 
                     SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet(); /* So we can set bold, and such */

                     keyCode.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode())); /* The key pressed */
                     keysPressed++;
                     currentPos = textPane.getCaretPosition(); /* The current position of the caret */

                     text = textPane.getText(); /* Grabbing the text on the text pane */
                     previousPos = text.lastIndexOf(" ", currentPos); /* Getting the last position of a space */
                     if(previousPos <= 0) /* If the position if before or equal to 0 */ 
                     {
                         previousPos = 0; /* Then the position is 0 */
                     }
                     length = currentPos - previousPos; /* The length of the string we're messing with, is between the two positions */
                     subText = text.substring(previousPos, currentPos); /* Grabbing the string between our two positions */
                     if(first) /* If this is the first letter, or insert */
                     {
                         if(keyCode.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT))
                         {
                             first = true;
                             subTextP = text.substring(0, 0); /* Then we want to grab it, at 0, 0 */
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             subTextP = text.substring(0, 0); /* Then we want to grab it, at 0, 0 */
                             first = false; /* it's no longer the first */
                         }
                     }
                     else /* If it isn't */
                     {
                         subTextP = text.substring(previousPos + 1, currentPos); /* Then we want to grab the usual */
                     }
                     subText = subText.replaceAll("[\\n\\t\\r]", ""); /* Getting rid of all the tabs and newlines */
                     subTextP = subTextP.replaceAll("[\\n\\t\\r]", ""); /*Getting rid of all the tabs and new lines */

                     if(keyCode.contains(KeyEvent.VK_3)) 
                     {
                         if(keyCode.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)) 
                         {
                             System.out.println("Number sign hit!");                                 
                             StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.GREEN); /* Anything following a number sign will be green */
                             doc.setCharacterAttributes(previousPos, length, sas, false);  /* Turning it green */
                         }
                     }
                     if(keyCode.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)) /* If a space has been hit! */
                     {
                         /* This is were we'll do all text coloring and such */
                         if(subText.equals(" if") || subText.equals("if") || subTextP.equals("if")) /* All things to be bolded */
                         {
                             StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.GRAY); /* All of these statements will be gray... */
                             StyleConstants.setBold(sas, true); /* ... and bold */
                             doc.setCharacterAttributes(previousPos, length, sas, false); /* Making them so! */
                             StyleConstants.setBold(sas, false); /* We don't want these attributes to remain... */
                             StyleConstants.setForeground(sas, Color.black); /* ... So we're removing them. */
                         }
                     }
                }

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
                {
                    for(int i = keysPressed; i >= 0; i--) /* For loop to remove all keyPresses from our list */
                    {
                        keyCode.remove(i); /* Removing the specified keyPress */
                    }
                    keysPressed = -1; /* Because the first index is 0, and we want to add one to keysPressed, we need to start below 0 */
                }

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                }
    });
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void start()
{
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public final static void main(String args[])
{
    new Main().start();
}

}
```

EDIT:

To reproduce the issue, run the code provided above. In the textPane, type in the word "if" (no quotes) and then hit the space-bar. The word should be bolded now, and a gray color. Now, try typing in a "#" (no quotes) after it, (space in-between) and hit space, or any other key; nothing happens. However, the system should print out "Number sign hit!" once you do input a "#", meaning the code is in fact still reachable. Also note that I use the *same* code (besides changing the colors) for the "#" as I do for the "if". Hope that helps you guys understand the problem a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's not correct to use `KeyListener` here.

Use `KeyBindings` or `DocumentListener` or `DocumentFilter` instead (or even replace the Document with own extension to override `insertString()` and `remove()` methods). You should change the highlight not only after space typing but also when somebody removes chars from the mid of the keyword.

Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to show real problem and provide steps to reproduce actual behaviour and describe desired behaviour.

Comment: Changed the posted code to an SSCCE, and added steps to reproduce the problem. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I typed "if #" and see the "Number sign hit!" in console. What's the problem?

Comment: As you can read in the steps I took to recreate the problem, or in the original post itself, the problem is that the number-sign, and everything after it are supposed to be green, which they aren't.